# Is iteration faster than recursion, or just less prone to stack overflows?

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration, stack-overflow

I know you can rewrite a recursive function using a simple loop by using an array as a first-in-first-out queue of 'work remaining to be done'. I have heard this makes it less likely to have a stack overflow.

But if stack overflows aren't an issue (because you're not recursing very deeply), is there any reason to prefer iterative over recursive? Is it any faster?

I'm mostly interested in JavaScript on V8.

Comment: You could try benchmarking it. If it is a small array I would go with the most readable solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Javascript, which doesn't (isn't required to, and perhaps can't? see the comments) do tail-recursion optimisation, recursion is both slower than iteration (because, in almost every language, a function call is *much* more expensive than a jump) and has the possibility of causing stack overflow errors if you recurse too deeply (however, the limit can be quite deep; Chrome gave up at recursion depth 16,316 in my experiment).

However, the performance impact is sometimes worth the clarity of the code you get when you write a recursive function, and certain things are a lot more difficult to do without recursion (recursive functions are almost always *much* shorter than their iterative counterparts), e.g. working with trees (but you don't really do that with Javascript much anyway *Edit:* GGG mentioned that the DOM is a tree, and working with that is very common in JS).

Comment: Great answer, explaining all the considerations when choosing a recusive or interative implemenation.  +1 for mentioning maintainability.

Comment: There was a question here recently that brought up the interesting  point that the existence of things like (non-standard) `Function#arguments` means real-world JS engines *can't* do tail call elimination... I assume they would do it otherwise whether or not it was required.

Comment: @GGG hmm, that's interesting. I added a note in my answer about that.

Comment: Also, I would consider the DOM to be a tree, and working with the DOM is extremely common in JS... and also, well-written iterative code can be shorter than recursive code and about equivalent in terms of readability... maybe I should post an answer, sorry for rambling in the comments ;)

Comment: @GGG, `arguments.caller` and `myFunction.arguments` are gone in EcmaScript 5 strict mode, so JS interpreters could optimize tail recursive strict functions.  See the 6th from the start and 2nd to last bullets of http://es5.github.com/#C

Comment: @MikeSamuel yeah, to my understanding this is exactly the reason those got axed.

Comment: @GGG, Not really.  It was more security reasons.  Mark Miller and I pushed for that for [SES](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=ses:ses).  That they enable certain other optimizations just helped sell them.

Comment: @MikeSamuel interesting, I had no idea... thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

Recursion may fail faster since an infinitely recursive function will blow out the stack producing an exception that the program can recover from, while an iterative solution will run until stopped by an outside agent.

For code that will produce a valid output given time, the main cost of recursion is function call overhead.  Iterative solutions simply don't have this, so tend to win in performance critical code in languages that don't explicitly optimize for recursion.

It's definitely noticeable in benchmarks, but unless you're writing performance critical code, your users probably won't notice.

The benchmarks at http://jsperf.com/function-call-overhead-test try to quantify function call overhead in various JS interpreters.  I would put together a similar benchmark that explicitly tests recursion if you're worried.

---

Note that tail-call recursion optimization is difficult to do correctly in EcmaScript 3.

For example, a simple implementation of array folding in JavaScript:

```
function fold(f, x, i, arr) {
  if (i === arr.length) { return x; }
  var nextX = f(x, arr[i]);
  return fold(f, nextX, i+1, arr);
}
```

cannot be tail-optimized because the call

```
 fold(eval, 'var fold=alert', 0, [0])
```

would `eval('var fold=alert')` inside the body of `fold`, causing the seemingly tail-recursive call to `fold` to not be actually recursive.

EcmaScript 5 changed `eval` to not be callable except via the name `eval`, and strict mode prevents `eval` from introducing local variables, but tail-call optimization depends on the ability to statically determine where a tail-call goes which is not always possible in dynamic languages like JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to run the following comparison, you can see the difference. In general iteration is faster, but sometimes the difference can be big if you happen to perform a lot of recursions.

```js
function factorialRec(n){
  if (n > 0) {
    return n * factorialRec(n - 1)
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

function factorial(n){
  var returnme = n;
  for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--){
    returnme *= i;
  }
  return returnme;
}

console.time('recursion')
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
  factorialRec(100);
}
console.timeEnd('recursion')

console.time('iteration')
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
  factorial(100);
}
console.timeEnd('iteration')
```

**Note**: Although the above example is quite convincing, in reality, you should not run into this many of function calls. So most of the time, the slowdown shouldn't be related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This depends... I was asking the same question when I was experiencing the "Slow script" error in IE8 in recursive function. And was surprised that iteration was actually even slower.

I was walking through a tree searching for a specific node. And I have rewritten my recursive function to iterative way (using stack to keep context) using the similar approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/159777/1245231

After that I however started getting much more "Slow script" errors from IE 8 than before. Doing some profiling confirmed that the iterative version was even slower.

The reason for this can be that using method call stack in JS is probably faster than using array with corresponding push() and pop() operations within a loop. To verify this I've created test that simulates tree walking in both cases: http://jsperf.com/recursion-vs-iteration-852 The results are surprising. While in Chrome the iterative version is (in my case) 19% slower, in IE8 the iterative version is 65% slower than the recursive version.

Comment: I've also found that an iterative implementation isn't always faster.

Comment: Try preallocating an array and maintaining the stack by tracking the current index. I bet that's a lot faster than push/pop. e.g. `var stack = new Array(size); var stack_index = 0;`

Comment: ah yes, IE8, what we all use to run our latest and most readable recursive code.

Comment: Maybe it is good to also check when it was answered. It was in 2013...